# Vanshaj of great Hindu Rishi Munis?

Tags: rishi, saint, ancestry

We all know that there were many great Rishi Munis (Sage) who have blessed our motherland and we also know that genes are passed on from one generation to the next one, so would it be correct to assume that among us, some where, we do have lineage of them?

Are there any known ones?

Comment: Yes, Brahmanas are descendants of Rishis.  Look up [Gotras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotra) and [Pravaras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pravaras).

Comment: From where do we get more information about this?

Comment: Actually all living beings are descendants of Rishis of Yore, but the main progenitors are Sapta Rishis who are the progenitors.  The Brahmanas when perform their daily Sandhya Vandana, invoke their ancestors at the end when they bow to the supreme Being.  The invocation has the name of the main two / three Rishis and the Gotra (lineage of the Rishi) of the person and the Veda followed by the person and his name - no mention of the immediate ascendants are made i.e son of so and so, grandson of so and so, etc.  Therefore the ancient lineage of the rishi is what is invoked daily.

Comment: Yes the Gotras that belong to these rishis signify the continuation of the same genealogy.